# Dirichelet Integral test limits

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to understand the $Dirichelet \ Integral \ test$

I see in many places that the integral is like this:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^k}dx$$

and if $k<=1$ it's $divergent$ otherwise it's $convergent$.

My question is about the lower limit. Can I use this test only on integrals starting at $1$ or it is valid for any given number?

Something like

$$\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^k}dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k>1$ then
$$\int_1^a\frac{1}{x^k}dx$$
is finite for any $a>0$, we have that
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}dx=
\int_1^a\frac{1}{x^k}dx+\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}dx,
$$
so
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}dx\quad\text{and}\quad\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}dx
$$
converge or diverge simultaneously (if $a>0$).

Comment: Tanks for your answer

Comment: Just a quick question. For type II improper integrals can I assume that the limits in $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^k}dx$ can be any kind?